# ImageMagick - How to crop around text

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, tesseract, scanning

I'm developing an app where you need to scan plate numbers and the images taken will obviously differ in range, some might be upclose and some might be further away. The closest I've come to a fix is by zooming in using the -distort SRT command, however, the plate number might get cut off depending on how close the user was when the photo was taken (or how zoomed in the camera is). Is there a way to crop an image around the text it contains?

ORIGINAL PICTURES 
[Plate 1](https://ibb.co/0f7Vqdm) 
[Plate 2](https://ibb.co/ZhpGNtr) 
[Plate 3](https://ibb.co/GVBqBp2) 
[Plate 4](https://ibb.co/4PPmxvt)

DESIRED OUTCOME 
[Plate 1](https://ibb.co/QMvc8hy) 
[Plate 2](https://ibb.co/jTT9vLN) 
[Plate 3](https://ibb.co/D4dsfK4) 
[Plate 4](https://ibb.co/XDtcHZr)

Comment: If you know where the text is to crop the image, then you already must have a solution. You pose a circular problem.  Won't tesseract read the text in those images?

Comment: Currently I'm just 'zooming' into the center of the image, but what if the user took a poorly image and the plate number isn't centered? My fix will either cut through the plate number (making it incomplete) or it might just be outside of the cropping area entirely. No, tesseract isn't having a good time with these pictures. Sometimes they do work with certain preprocessing effects, but not all of them. Plate 4 is especially tough to get working with tesseract due to the raindrops.